# Django redirect to different page based on choice

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I need to add redirect to the next page in Django based on Payment choice. So if customer click pay on delivery or pay on local pickup, then redirect should be to the page where he will see details etc. If he chose pay by bank transfer, there should be redirect to the different page where he will see bank account details. Actually I have everything ready just need to code for redirect and i dont know if i should to do that on template or in the views. Any recommendations please ?

Answer (score 0):

In your views I would filter on the selection. And based on selection return a different page.

views.py

```
def checkout(request):
    if local_pickup:
        return render(request, 'localpickup.html', context)
    elif bank_transfer:
        return render(request, 'banktransfer.html', context)
    else:
        ....
```

Something along the lines of that is what I would do.